# url codeigniter for multilanguage website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need language appear in the url for multilanguage website. Here is my code:

```
public function changeLang($lang_code){
                    $this->session->set_userdata('language',$lang_code);
                    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."".$this->language);
                }
```

When i write this way another language appears in url. For example, whatever language i chose it gives for english http://localhost/new/en. or it increments http://localhost/new/enen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess. Before redirect: if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],-2)!=$Lang_code)

Comment: Hello Andreas, thanks for the answer. In my case at least it didnt work:(

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to make multi language application and identify the language by url, isn't it?

If yes, i recommend you create a controller in your application/core

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function redirect( $language = NULL ){
        $this->_set_language($language);

        $uri                = array(
                                    'direcotry'     => $this->_get_directory(),
                                    'class'         => $this->_get_class(),
                                    'method'        => $this->_get_method(),
                                    'language'      => $this->get_language()
                                    );

        return $uri;
    }

    public function get_language(){
        $this->language     = ( empty($this->session->userdata('language'))) ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2) : $this->session->userdata('language');

        return $this->language;
    }

    private function _set_language( $language ){
        $this->session->set_userdata('language', $language);

        $this->_set_lang_language();
    }

    private function _set_lang_language( $language = '' ){
        switch($language){
            case 'en':
                        $new    = 'english';
                        break;
            case 'es':
                        $new    = 'spanish';
                        break;
            default:
                        $new    = 'english';
                        break;
        }

        $this->lang->load('calendar', $new);
        $this->lang->load('date', $new);
        $this->lang->load('db', $new);
        $this->lang->load('email', $new);
        $this->lang->load('form_validation', $new);
        $this->lang->load('ftp', $new);
        $this->lang->load('imglib', $new);
        $this->lang->load('number', $new);
        $this->lang->load('profiler', $new);
        $this->lang->load('unit_test', $new);
        $this->lang->load('upload', $new);
    }
}
```

You will have a selected language in your header o something like that, wen you make click in a specific language, you will call the uri homepage/change/{$language}
your normal controller

```
class HomePage extends MY_Controller{
    public function change ( $language = '', $uri = NULL ){
        $this->redirect($language);

        redirect($uri, 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello elddenmedio, thanks for the reply, It gave me an error. `Error

Message: Call to undefined method Home::redirect()`. But I found another solution to this: "public function changeLang($lang_code='', $uri = NULL){
            $this->lang->load('main', $lang_code=='' ? 'english' : $lang_code);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('language',$lang_code);
                    $this->view->load('front/inc/navigation');
                    
                }"

Comment: Now i have another issue. In url language appears but also controller and method name appear home/changeLang/en. May be in the route I can change? or what would you suggest. Also for some languages it cant read the page with language for example it reads with http://localhost/new url, but it cant recognize with http://localhost/de. but it reads with english. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, i forgot in every controller you need to put this in your constructor                `function __construct(){
  $_language = ( isset( $this->session->userdata('language'))) ? $this->session->userdata('language') : 'english';
  
  $this->lang->load('calendar', $new);
        $this->lang->load('date', $new);
        $this->lang->load('db', $new);
        $this->lang->load('email', $new);
 }`

Comment: Thank you, elddenmedio. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a url like

```
site.com/controller/change_language/{language}
```

controller.php

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function change_language( $lang = 'english'){
        $new = $this->session->set_userdata('language', $lang);

        $this->lang->load('calendar', $new);
        $this->lang->load('date', $new);
        $this->lang->load('db', $new);
        $this->lang->load('email', $new);
        $this->lang->load('form_validation', $new);
        $this->lang->load('ftp', $new);
        $this->lang->load('imglib', $new);
        $this->lang->load('number', $new);
        $this->lang->load('profiler', $new);
        $this->lang->load('unit_test', $new);
        $this->lang->load('upload', $new);

        redirect(base_url, 'refresh');
    }
}
```

With this you save the new language in a session, and you prevent an error by url.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: yeah exactly, i have url like that. Great thanks. I will try that